# Spring Boot Testing: exception in REST controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application and want to cover my REST controllers by integration test.
Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tools/port-scan")
public class PortScanController {
    private final PortScanService service;

    public PortScanController(final PortScanService portScanService) {
        service = portScanService;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public final PortScanInfo getInfo(
            @RequestParam("address") final String address,
            @RequestParam(name = "port") final int port)
            throws InetAddressException, IOException {
        return service.scanPort(address, port);
    }
}
```

In one of test cases I want to test that endpoint throws an exception in some circumstances. Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(PortScanController.class)
public class PortScanControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private static final String PORT_SCAN_URL = "/tools/port-scan";

    @Test
    public void testLocalAddress() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get(PORT_SCAN_URL).param("address", "192.168.1.100").param("port", "53")).andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do that? Current implementation doesn't handle InetAddressException which is thrown from PortScanController.getInfo() and when I start test, I receive and error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.handytools.webapi.exceptions.InetAddressException: Site local IP is not supported
```

It is not possible to specify expected exception in @Test annotation since original InetAddressException is wrapped with NestedServletException.

Answer (score 10):

Spring Boot Test package comes with [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) that has very convenient way of verifying thrown exceptions.

To verify cause:

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowException() {
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> methodThrowingException()).hasCause(InetAddressException .class);
}
```

There are also few more methods that you may be interested in. I suggest having a look in [docs](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html).

Answer (score 4):

In order to test the wrapped exception (i.e., InetAddressException), you can create a JUnit Rule using `ExpectedException` class and then set the `expectMessage()` (received from `NestedServletException`'s `getMessage`(), which contains the actual cause), you can refer the below code for the same:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException inetAddressExceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testLocalAddress() {

    //Set the message exactly as returned by NestedServletException
    inetAddressExceptionRule.expectMessage("Request processing failed; nested exception is com.handytools.webapi.exceptions.InetAddressException: Site local IP is not supported");

     //or you can check below for actual cause 
     inetAddressExceptionRule.expectCause(org.hamcrest.Matchers.any(InetAddressException.class))

    //code for throwing InetAddressException here (wrapped by Spring's NestedServletException)
}
```

You can refer the ExpectedException API here:

http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. As I mentioned in my question, original exception is wrapped with NestedServletException.

Comment: Already done it. It doesn't work. jUnit doesn't handle this exception.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it doesn't work. The problem is that mvc.perform() throws NestedServletException which has nested InetAddressException exception.

Comment: In addition, I don't think that handling NestedServletException is a good idea, since it is more general exception and can be caused by different reasons, not only by InetAddressException.

Comment: @DavyJohnes Check my update, we need to check for expectMessage, ensure that it exactly same as returned by NestedServletException.getMessage()

Comment: thanks a lot. However, your solution looks like workaround. Ideal solution for me is to instruct MockMvc to expect particular exception.

Answer (score 2):

You could define an exception handler

```
@ExceptionHandler(InetAddressException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
public Response handledInvalidAddressException(InetAddressException e)
{
    log e
    return getValidationErrorResponse(e);
}
```

and then in your test you could do

```
mvc.perform(get(PORT_SCAN_URL)
   .param("address", "192.168.1.100")
   .param("port", "53"))
   .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response").exists())
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response.code", is(400)))
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.response.errors[0].message", is("Site local IP is not supported")));
```

Comment: Thanks, Borys. How can I do that, taking into account that I have autoconfigured MockMvc instance?

Comment: I meant an exception handler for your application, not your test. So that your application declares `@ExceptionHandler(InetAddressException.class)`, and then responds with a 400 or 503 status code with a message that describes an error, then your test looks for the expected status code and expected error message in response.

Comment: because what you get is really a validation error, and therefore a 400 code along with an error message seems appropriate to me

Comment: I agree, but Sping Boot itself handles such exception somehow, I mean it returns a JSON response which contain Exception message and other details. So, I guess Spring Boot has some kind of default exception handler and I just want to reuse this "default" handler in my tests.

Comment: where i should define this handler method?

Comment: you could create handler method in your request handling class (or move such handler methods to the base class)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i fix it with `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatExceptionOfType` :

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowInetAddressException() {
    assertThatExceptionOfType(InetAddressException.class)
        .isThrownBy(() -> get(PORT_SCAN_URL).param("address", "192.168.1.100").param("port", "53"));
}
```

I hope it's help you !